# Django admin, when I choose a category, brands are selected for this category only

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

please help me!!

I have a problem:

I have a model Category, Brand, Product.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Brand(models.Model):
    name ...

class Product(models.Model):
    name = ...
    category = models.Foreinkey(Category, ...)
    brand = models.Foreinkey(Brand, ...)
    price = ...
```

I need:

in Django admin, when I choose a category, brands are selected for this category only, for example:

Phones - LG, Huawei ... etc.

Laptops - Acer, Asus ... etc.

if you know how to do it, please